# Map json to object with multiple "" in java

Tags: java, json, string, objectmapper, jsonparser

i'm trying to use object mapper to convert a json string to an object class, but it keep return UnrecognizedPropertyException

here is the return json string

> {"errorCode":400,"Message":"ORA-01403: no data found\nORA-06512: at \"CSS_HPG.SELFCARE_LAY_DS_GOITRATRUOC\", line 12\nORA-06512: at line 1","Data":null}

here is my class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
*
* @author Autumn
*/
public class PackageSearchOutput {

int errorCode;
List<String> Message;
PackageSearchOutputData Data;

public PackageSearchOutput(int errorCode, List<String> Message, 
PackageSearchOutputData Data) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
    this.Message = Message;
    this.Data = Data;
}


public PackageSearchOutput() {
}

public List<String> getMessage() {
    return Message;
}

public void setMessage(ArrayList<String> Message) {
    this.Message = Message;
}

public int getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
}

public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
}



public PackageSearchOutputData getData() {
    return Data;
}

public void setData(PackageSearchOutputData Data) {
    this.Data = Data;
}
```

}

here is my mapping code

```
result = mapper.readValue(output.toString(), PackageSearchOutput.class);
```

here is the detail error 
[click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cc9i.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UnrecognizedPropertyException` is because `Message` is not a recognized property.

Without annotations, the default name of the fields start with lowercase, e.g. `message`, but your JSON text has `Message`, which is a different name (since they are case-sensitive).

To use non-default property names, add `@JsonProperty` annotations:

```
@JsonProperty("Message")
public List<String> getMessage() {
```

```
@JsonProperty("Data")
public PackageSearchOutputData getData() {
```

Once you do that, you're likely going to run into the issue of `Message` being a `String`, while your class defines it as a `List<String>`, so that may fail. You might need to change the `Message` field and its getter and setter from `List<String>` to `String`.